# 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I am trying to backup mysql using the command

```
mysqldump -u root -p  database_name > backup.sql
```

, but it is throwing an error:

> 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s)
> for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

Also, I wanted to make a backup my database with all tables seperately stored as a file. How can I do it?

mysql version = 5.7.31

Comment: Related: Why does mysqldump still return exit code 0 when this error happens?

Answer (score 296):

use `--no-tablespaces`

see [mysqldump-Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

> **mysqldump** requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables,
> SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, LOCK TABLES
> if the --single-transaction option is not used, and (as of MySQL
> 8.0.21) PROCESS if the --no-tablespaces option is not used.
> Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option
> descriptions.

and see documentation of param [no-tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-tablespaces)

> --no-tablespaces, -y
>
> This option suppresses all CREATE LOGFILE GROUP and CREATE TABLESPACE
> statements in the output of mysqldump.

Comment: In the 5.7 branch, this has changed in MySQL 5.7.31.

Comment: Thanks!  My backup script was failing on Lightsail and I didn't know why, but I see that they just upgraded to MySQL 8.0.21.  All I had to do was add --no-tablespaces, which I don't really need for the type of simple backup I am trying to perform.

Comment: `--no-tablespaces` fixed the issue in my scenario and I expect many others. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 113):

**tl;dr** Breaking change introduced in minor MySQL update, use `--no-tablespaces` option in `mysqldump` from now on (recommended) or add the global `PROCESS` privilege to the user running the command.

I experienced the same issue on some of my machines. Not all at once, not on all commands, not on all users.

**Why not all at once?**

Turns out this is a breaking change introduced in MySQL minor updates 5.7.31 and 8.0.21 in 2020/07.

See [5.7.31 Release Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-31.html#mysqld-5-7-31-security) / [8.0.21 Release Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-21.html#mysqld-8-0-21-security)

> Security Notes
>
> > **Incompatible Change**: Access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES table now requires the PROCESS privilege.
> >
> > This change affects users of the mysqldump command, which accesses tablespace information in the FILES table, and thus now requires the PROCESS privilege as well. Users who do not need to dump tablespace information can work around this requirement by invoking mysqldump with the --no-tablespaces option. (Bug #30350829)

The said issue number should be available here http://mybug.no.oracle.com/orabugs/bug.php?id=30350829. Oracles bug tracker seems to be down however. Another public issue is https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100219.

So this issue has to happen on all machines having MySQL >= 5.7 and getting system updates eventually.

Breaking Changes in minor updates are unexpected. This is a security issue however. It's a pity that this issue and how to solve it is not communicated better. Imho a more practical solution for this breaking change would be to removed tablespaces in `mysqldump` by default and add a `--add-tablespaces` option instead.

**Why not on all commands?**

The said privilege `PROCESS` is not needed for most use cases. `mysqldump` however tries to access the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES` table, which - as said above - now requires the PROCESS privilege.

So `mysqldump` now needs to be started by a user with enough privileges or using the `--no-tablespaces` option.

See [mysqldump documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used, and (*as of MySQL 5.7.31*) PROCESS if the --no-tablespaces option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

See [--no-tablespaces documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-tablespaces)

> This option suppresses all CREATE LOGFILE GROUP and CREATE TABLESPACE statements in the output of mysqldump.

See [process documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process)

> The PROCESS privilege controls access to information about threads executing within the server (that is, information about statements being executed by sessions).
> The PROCESS privilege also enables use of the SHOW ENGINE statement, access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA InnoDB tables (tables with names that begin with INNODB_), and (*as of MySQL 5.7.31*) access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA FILES table.

What a [MySQL tablespace is why it is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805316/what-is-a-tablespace-and-why-is-it-used) is explained very well in another question on StackOverflow already.

General advice: Most users do not need the tablespace information and may therefore safely ignore it using the `--no-tablespace` option.

If tablespaces are configured knowingly and willingly, then the user doing the mysqldumps should get sufficient privileges.

**Why not on all users?**

The MySQL `root` user is not affected of course. Other users may or may not be affected depending on the way they are given privileges.

The `GRANT` option adds privileges on a global level, or a single database, a single table, or even columns or routines. Some privileges, like the said `PROCESS` privilege, need to be added on a global level.

See [grant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-privileges)

> The following table summarizes the permissible privilege types that can be specified for the GRANT and REVOKE statements, and the levels at which each privilege can be granted.
>
> | Privilege | Meaning and Grantable Levels |
>
> | PROCESS | Enable the user to see all processes with SHOW PROCESSLIST. Level: Global. |

So the sql command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON somedatabase.* TO someuser@localhost;` will add all *available* privileges to the user on one database only. Global privileges are added using `ON *.*`.

In my case most databases users had privileges for selected databases only. Check the users privileges with `SHOW GRANTS for someuser@localhost;`.

To add the global privilege use the SQL command `GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO someuser@localhost;`. *Don't do this unless you know about the consequences of this privilege*. To the revoke the privilege use `REVOKE PROCESS ON *.* FROM someuser@localhost;`.

Comment: `GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO someuser@localhost;` did solve the issue. :)

Comment: This only mentions 5.7.x and 8.0.x, but this is also the case in 5.6.x ([v5.6.49 to be precise](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-49.html#mysqld-5-6-49-security)).

Comment: -- CREATE DUMPER 'dump'@'localhost'
CREATE USER 'dump'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'any-pass';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'dump'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER, PROCESS ON `cheapmarina`.* TO 'dump'@'localhost';
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'dump'@'localhost';
i dont have eno reputation, SWAG

Answer (score 12):

Resolve by adding:

```
--column-statistics=0 --no-tablespaces
```

to your dump command. I had to add the column-statistics also as just no-tablespaces was not working.

Comment: *`--column-statistics=0 --no-tablespaces`*. That works on mysqldump command. I'm using mysqlworkbench 8.0.19 but couldn't find these options in advanced options section of data export.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

Also, I got the error below:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'john'@'localhost' to database 'apple' when selecting the database

When I tried to export `apple` database to `backup.sql` with the user `john` as shown below:

```
mysqldump -u john -p apple > backup.sql
```

So, I gave [PROCESS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) to the user `john` with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) by login with the user `root` as shown below:

```sql
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Also, I gave all privileges on all the tables in `apple` database (`apple.*`) to the user `john` with `GRANT` by login with the user `root` as shown below, then I could solve these errors:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON apple.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON apple.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

In addition, you could solve these errors by giving all privileges on all the tables in all database (`*.*`) to the user `john` with `GRANT` by login with the user `root` as shown below:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is failing for you in Workbench, try to use the command line instead.

First find the path of your mysqldump tool

```bash
find / -name "*mysqldump*"
# probably /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Then the following command (Replace DB_HOST, DB_PORT and DB_USER).You can then export the password:

```bash
export MYSQL_PWD=DB_PASSWORD
```

And then run this command

```bash
/usr/bin/mysqldump \
--host=DB_HOST \
--port=DB_PORT \
--default-character-set=utf8 \
--user=DB_USER \
--protocol=tcp \
--single-transaction=TRUE > mydump.sql
```

Comment: A better (and more universal) way to handle this in mysql-workbench is to add `no-tablespaces = true` to `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf`